# How to design alert box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, alert

It shows me a simple Alert Box when I use this

```
<button onclick="alert('AlertBox')">Click Me</button>
```

But is their any way to have an alert box, with extra bg color and some extra effect look?

Answer (score 0):

use [Sweet Alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Or Make div with fixed position display none, and in javascript when you click on botton change div display to block

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. Sweet Alert is best! Wow

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed example of Designed Alert Box with help of Sweet Alerts

http://javainfinite.com/html/custom-designed-alerts/

Answer (score 0):

The javascript alert() is a system message box that will will block your page whilst it displays and will look different on different operating systems.

What you are looking for is usually referred to as a dialog box or modal popup, these are constructed using html and javascript to look like the page behind is blocked or greyed out.

If you are starting out, you could look at some examples like:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
These are build from scratch.

Or you could look at using a css librarly like BootStrap which will have these components and other components to help style your website or application.
eg: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/